# Mysql Range Dynamically with values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table where my levels are stored and points required to upgrade to another level like this:

```
id | level | pointsrequired
-----------------------------
1  | 0     | 0
2  | 1     | 20
3  | 2     | 50
4  | 3     | 90
```

Now this points required can be dynamic so not sure I use the fix case value, I want to check if my current point is greater than previous one and less than next one my level should be upgraded or else its fine.

This is the query which I came for but not sure is this proper solution or not.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pointsrequired BETWEEN 25 AND  (SELECT MAX(pointsrequired) FROM tbl) LIMIT 1
```

Like previously my points were 0 and now I got 25 then, I should be upgraded to Level 2
Any another solution not sure about this.

Comment: What should the desired result look like (preferably for a variety of inputs)? See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for 25 you'd like to get level 2?

```
SELECT
      `id`
    , `level`
    , `pointsrequired`
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    pointsrequired <= 25
ORDER BY
    pointsrequired DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Er, this doesn't do that

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT `level` FROM tbl WHERE pointsrequired > 25 ORDER BY pointsrequired LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think the query return 50 that is not reached yet with 25 points. I've added answer with slightly modified query: ordering DESC and getting records that smaller that entered value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t1
WHERE
    pointsrequired BETWEEN 25 AND
        (SELECT t2.pointsrequired FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.pointsrequired > 25
         ORDER BY t2.pointsrequired LIMIT 1);
```

The subquery finds the next immediate level which is higher than the input value of 25.